# change paragraph font size

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to reduce or increase the font size of each paragraph in my document to fill a one and only line in each page (in the center of the page).

The paragraphs may contain 2 or more words. Paragraphs containing few words should have a bigger font size to fit a line.

I tried this code:

```vb
Sub para_line

    For Each Para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        f = 10
        varDis = 500

        varDis = Para.Range.Characters.Last.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
        Do While varDis < 140 Or f < 150
            varDis = Para.Range.Characters.Last.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
            Para.Range.Font.SizeBi = f

            f = f + 5
        Loop
    Next

End Sub
```

I don't want to expand or condense the characters.

Comment: What specific problem did you run into with your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Test result demo

[image: Test result demo]

```vb
Sub SetOneLinePerPage()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim rng As Range, p As Paragraph
    Dim currentPage As Integer, ur As UndoRecord
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "SetOneLinePerPage"
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
'    pageWidth = doc.PageSetup.pageWidth
'    pageHeight = doc.PageSetup.pageHeight
    
    For Each p In doc.Paragraphs
        Set rng = p.Range
        With rng
            If InStr(Chr(13) & Chr(12) & Chr(47), Left(rng, 1)) = 0 _
               And Not rng.Information(wdWithInTable) And _
               Not rng.Information(wdInContentControl) Then
            
            ' Adjust the font size of the paragraph to match the line
                ' reset paragraph alignment
                .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
                
                Do While .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) > 1
                    .Font.Size = .Font.Size - 1
                    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing - 1
                Loop
                .Font.Size = .Font.Size + 1
                .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing + 1
                
                Do While .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) = 1
                    .Font.Size = .Font.Size + 1
                    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing + 1
                Loop
                .Font.Size = .Font.Size - 1
                .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing - 1

                
                CenterParagraphOnPage rng
                
                If .Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) = currentPage Then
                    Stop
                End If
                
                currentPage = .Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            End If
        End With
    Next p
    
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub

Sub CenterParagraphOnPage(rng As Range)
    Dim pageHeight  As Single, textHeight As Long, TopMargin As Single
    With rng
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .ParagraphFormat.BaseLineAlignment = wdBaselineAlignCenter
        
        pageHeight = .PageSetup.pageHeight ' - rng.PageSetup.TopMargin - rng.PageSetup.BottomMargin
        
'        textHeight = .Font.Size * .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines)
        
        TopMargin = pageHeight / 2 '- textHeight / 2
    
        .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = TopMargin
        
    End With
End Sub
```